# How can query last 5 minutes of records?

Tags: sql, oracle

How I can to see last 5 mins record before the current time through sql query how i can do this.
The format of time stamp is

```
03/25/2014 14:00:00
```

I used this query for the same

```
SELECT Time stamp FROM TABLE 
WHERE S >1 AND SUBSTRING((Time stamp,15,2)-5)
```

is this fine of any other way to do the same

Comment: What flavor of RDBMS? mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle DB2 etc?  Think for a second as well.  Do you do math on string data? keeping it as a timestamp and finding a function that lets you do math with time is likely a better answer.

Comment: ORACLE db and simple sql queries for extracting data

Answer (score 13):

If you are using MySQL and your `timestamp` column is of data type `datetime` you can do

```
SELECT Timestamp 
FROM your_table
WHERE Timestamp >= now() - interval 5 minute
```

Comment: In the table which I am using there is a field of raisetime in which different time stamps are given for example my current raisetime is in this format '03/25/2014 14:00:00'.I want to subtract 5 mins from it and see the records before it.how i can do this

Answer (score 12):

If your timestamp is a date column, you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.timestamp >= sysdate - 5/(24*60)
```

Things are a bit more interesting if `timestamp` is a character column.  Then you need to translate it to a date/time:

```
select t.*
from table t
where to_date(t.timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= sysdate - 5/(24*60)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
select *
from the_table
where timestamp_column <= timestamp '2014-03-25 14:00:00' - interval '5' minute;
```

This assumes that `timestamp_column` is defined with the data type `timestamp`.

If it isn't you should stop **now** and re-define your table to use the correct data type.

---

The expression `timestamp '2014-03-25 14:00:00'` is a (ANSI SQL) timestamp *literal*.

It's equivalent to `to_timestamp('2014-03-25 14:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` but I prefer the ANSI literal because it's less typing and works across multiple DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to get 5 minutes ago in oracle.  subtracting from a timestamp in increments of 1 where 1 is a day. so 5 minutes would be 5/(24hours*60min) of a day.

```
SELECT sysdate, sysdate-(5/(24*60)) as min_Ago5 from dual
```